# Symfony phpunit - Accessing the "validator" service directly from the container is deprecated, use dependency injection instead

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

A deprecation notice is complaining about this line in `setUp()` in a phpunit test file:

```
$this->validator = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('validator');
```

It says:

```
Accessing the "validator" service directly from the container is deprecated, use dependency injection instead.
```

What is the correct way to update this to use dependency injection instead?

Answer (score 2):

I changed it to this, according to the docs at https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#retrieving-services-in-the-test (which is mentioned in the answer, but I thought I would post to clarify and show the code change I made)

```
self::bootKernel(); 
$container = static::getContainer(); 
$this->validator = $container->get('validator');
```

This gets rid of the deprecation warning.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the validator, you can use the ConstraintValidatorTestCase

and if you have a custom validator with a dependency to a service, well you have to have the deprecated message, i believe :/

https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#retrieving-services-in-the-test

https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#testing-custom-constraints

You could mock the dependency but that would not be really tested then :/